# Retornar um array com os N primeiros números pares

Tags: javascript

Escreva uma função que, recebendo um número N como parâmetro, retorne os N primeiros números pares (por exemplo, se N for 3, você deve imprimir 0, 2 e 4; se N for 5, deve retornar 0, 2, 4, 6 e 8).

```
function retornaNNumerosPares(n) {

    let numerosPares = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            numerosPares.push(i)
        }
    }
    return numerosPares;
}
retornaNNumerosPares(5)
```

Ele para no 2, o 4 não entra no array.

Comment: https://ideone.com/AdOcis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você invocar a função `retornaNNumerosPares` passando *5* como parâmetro, então o seu laço *for* só irá rodar 5 vezes... de 0 a 4.

Se você quer que ele rode até encontrar 5 números pares poderia fazer um *for* com a condição `numerosPares.length < n`, dessa forma o *for* continuaria rodando até que o seu *array* tenha 5 itens:

```js
function retornaNNumerosPares(n) {
    let numerosPares = [];
    for (let i = 0; numerosPares.length < n; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            numerosPares.push(i);
        }
    }
    return numerosPares;
}

console.log(retornaNNumerosPares(5));
```

Também podemos tornar a função mais eficiente incrementando *i* de 2 em 2 ao invés de verificar se o resto é igual a 0:

```js
function retornaNNumerosPares(n) {
    let numerosPares = [];
    for (let i = 0; numerosPares.length < n; i += 2) {
        numerosPares.push(i);
    }
    return numerosPares;
}

console.log(retornaNNumerosPares(5));
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Uma definição para o conjunto do números naturais pares pode ser obtida com:

[image: conjunto do números naturais pares]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, se quisermos determinar os primeiros Números Naturais Pares, teremos que percorrer um a um o Conjunto do Números Naturais iniciando do zero até o número que corresponda a quantidade de números desejados e a cada iteração visitar basta multiplicar o natural iterado por dois assim obtendo o correspondente. Obtendo os quatro primeiros naturais pares:

| ℕ | par correspondente |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 6 |

Diante a breve explicação para fazer o reparo do seu algoritmo:

- Remova comparação `if (i % 2 == 0)`, onde testa a paridade do contador, pois é desnecessária.
- Ao invés de fazer `numerosPares.push(i)`, adicione o dobro do contador `numerosPares.push(2 * i)`.

```js
function retornaNNumerosPares(n) {
  let numerosPares = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    numerosPares.push(2 * i);
  }
  return numerosPares;
}

console.log(retornaNNumerosPares(6));
```

É possível simplificar o algoritmo usando um laço [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) ao criar um Array de n elementos e com a ajuda do método[`Array.prototype.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) iterar pelos naturais de `[0,n[`:

```js
function retornaNNumerosPares(n) {
  let numerosPares = [];
  for (let i of new Array(n).keys()) {
    numerosPares.push(2 * i);
  }
  return numerosPares;
}

console.log(retornaNNumerosPares(6));
```

Seguindo o raciocínio funcional pode-se usar o método estático [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) para criar um array de indices de `[0,n[` e aplicar uma função a cada elemento:

```js
const retornaNNumerosPares = (n) => Array.from(new Array(n).keys(), e => 2 * e);

console.log(retornaNNumerosPares(5));
```

Ou ainda com `Array.from()` se valer de um objeto com a propriedade `length` configurada em `n` e então manipular os indices do arra gerado:

```js
const retornaNNumerosPares = (n) => Array.from({length: n}, (_, i) => 2 * i);

console.log(retornaNNumerosPares(10));
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
function retornaNNumerosPares(n) {
  let numerosPares = [];
  for (let i = 0; numerosPares.length < n; i += 2) {
    numerosPares.push(i);
  }
  return numerosPares;
}

console.log(retornaNNumerosPares(5));
```